# Unity Netcode for gameobjects, NetworkList results in Memory leak

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm having a problem with unity's netcode NetworkList, it Works fine when testing in editor except that I get two error messages saying "A Native Collection has not been disposed, resulting in a memory leak". I already checked and know that the error comes from me creating a NetworkList, but I don't know how to fix this or what I'm doing wrong. I have already spent a lot of time on this, please help.

```
public class Vehicle_Handler : NetworkBehaviour
{
    // private 
    [SerializeField] new Renderer renderer;
    public NetworkList<bool> seats = new NetworkList<bool>();
    public bool hasDriver;
 



    void Update()
    {
        if (seats.Count == 0)
        {
            seats.Add(false);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            seats[0] = !seats[0];
            Debug.Log(seats[0]);
        }
        renderer.enabled = seats[0];
    }
}
```

it's pretty much an empty script but it gives off an error and I've no clue as to why. I'm a bit ashamed to ask this but I can't find documentation or examples for this.

Comment: If the error says "has not been disposed", you are most likely not disposing an object. So check if any classes you are using implements `IDisposable` and ensure that you dispose any such objects.

Answer (score 2):

[`NetworkList`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0/api/Unity.Netcode.NetworkList-1.html) internally is allocating [`NativeList`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.collections@2.2/api/Unity.Collections.NativeList-1.html)

See [source](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects/blob/81fd4ef9d875acafe8601ae417b794cddd9603c8/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects/Runtime/NetworkVariable/Collections/NetworkList.cs#L14)

> ```
> private NativeList<T> m_List = new NativeList<T>(64, Allocator.Persistent);
> private NativeList<NetworkListEvent<T>> m_DirtyEvents = new NativeList<NetworkListEvent<T>>(64, Allocator.Persistent);
> ```

You should properly `Dispose` it when not needed anymore

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    seats?.Dispose();
}
```

---

Are here going to be more values in that list at all? Why synchronize an entire list if only ever using the first item?

Comment: The Errors are still there. Though I should have noted that the Errors pop up when the game/scene starts

Comment: There are going to be more values, I need to store a list of values and i didn't know how to do it, so i made a test script.

Comment: In general it might be better / required to only initialize the list in `Awake`, not directly at field initialization

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a link for docs](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/networkvariable/index.html#custom-networkvariable-implementations)

```
private NetworkList<AreaWeaponBooster> TeamAreaWeaponBoosters;

void Awake()
{
    //NetworkList can't be initialized at declaration time like NetworkVariable. It must be initialized in Awake instead.
    //If you do initialize at declaration, you will run into Memmory leak errors.
    TeamAreaWeaponBoosters = new NetworkList<AreaWeaponBooster>(); 
}
```